# The best place to store a user-accessible configuration file

Tags: android, configuration, preferences, configuration-files

I have a project consisting of four programs for different platforms; all of them use the same XML-based settings file format. I want to be able to manually modify/overwrite it outside of the application. On Windows, Windows Mobile and Linux I'm using "user.home", but on Android that alias isn't implemented. I'm thinking about simply putting it in the Downloads directory, however, that doesn't feel right.

I can't be the only one, who needs that kind of functionality. Or this isn't Android-way? Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: I'm OK with the settings file not being available all the time (i.e. SD-card removed), it's used only on the start-up of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29). This would work only if the device has an external storage. The user would be able to access it.

However, take note of the following from the docs:

> External files are not always available: they will disappear if the
>   user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it. See the
>   APIs on Environment for information in the storage state.

Comment: Thank you, seen that, but I'm not sure what this means: `These files are private to the applications, and not typically visible to the user as media`. And I can't test it, since I don't have a real device right now.

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo That sentence means that *media* files present in those directories are not typically shown to the user by apps like Gallery. I've verified on a device that such files can be accessed by the user. On my device the external files dir is: `/mnt/sdcard/Android/your.package.name/files/`

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android data storage documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) you have 5 options:

1. Shared Preferences. By default this will use file `/data/data/your.package.name/preferences/user_preferences.xml`
2. Internal Storage. Here you can use something like `/data/data/you.package.name/user.home`
3. External Storage. Similar to internal storage `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/your.package.name/user.home`, but if user removes memory card file will be inaccessible.
4. SQLiteDatabase. You can store the whole `user.home` file in a database blob.
5. NetworkConnection. Store user's config in a cloud.

Comment: 1, 2 and 4 - user can't access these folders on a non-rooted device (right?). Moreover, 4 isn't an option, since that's an overkill for a config file, and 5 isn't acceptable, because the internet access isn't guaranteed. 3 - is that a standard location? If so - will I be able to browse it from a computer (on a connected device)?

Comment: Figured it out: `Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer`.

Comment: this is an over-long list, the OP wants a user-accessible file. the only one is really option 3...